# Неправильный парсинг строки из удаленного сервиса

Tags: java, строки

Из удаленного сервиса приходит произвольная строка.

В зависимости от наличия `"Body:"` подстроки я должен парсить ее различными способами я делаю вот так:

```
    String longString = service.getString();

    if (longString.indexOf("Body:") != -1) {
        // some code
    } else {
        // enother code
    }
```

Но когда приходит строка вида `"Body:\Dsdqwe...."` логика отрабатывает из блока `else`. Почему так и как можно пофиксить ?

Comment: а почему `\D`, а не `\\D` ?

Comment: Это сервис что приходит то приходит.

Comment: А как точно выглядит строка  именно из сервиса? Потому что на `"Body:\Dsdqwe"` вообще кмк, должна выскакивать ошибка, а не попадать в какое-то из условий.....ибо это невалид....либо надо что-то "эскейпить" http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-escape-a-string-for-java.html

Comment: А может быть такое что `\D` трактуется как удаление символа или что то в этом роде и поэтому строку `Body:` не находит ?

Comment: Может. именно поэтому  мои комментарии и написаны)

Comment: если взять `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` и применение на строке `longString = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(longString);` - результаты дало или нет (как я указано в ссылке, которую я оставлял)?